# Arithmetic regarding a bounded interval within modulo line in c

Tags: c, math, intervals

I am trying to find arithmetic, as I have no identifiers, to find a set within a line for c though language doesn't really matter. Here it is:

I will have a constantly increasing set of lines and each of these lines has 16 members. My goal is to do something for each of the 16 members only on every 128th line. So, when i gets to 128 I want to find arithmetic to allow the 16 members of this line to be allowed but as soon as it moves to the next line, 144, don't allow it. It was easily hardcoded, but I need a generic solution.

So, obviously mod is needed. The way I brainstormed was that I need to reference the 0th member of every128th line as starting point. So I wanted to somehow say if you're on the 15th member of line 128 (143), minus 15 and make sure %128==0.

Bytesourcepos is the number (i.e. 128)

So this is what I have:
    ((Bytesourcepos-(Bytesourcepos -128))%128==0;

The problem here is that this always is true for anything that is 128 and up. Somehow I need to integrate the bound of doing it 16 times from the starting point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `(Bytesourcepos-(Bytesourcepos -128)` --> `+128`.  So `((Bytesourcepos-(Bytesourcepos -128))%128==0` --> `128%128==0` --> `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume everything is 0-indexed, and that you count the 0th line as being a line you want. If you want it to be 1-indexed, this answer changes only slightly.

Take your position, `pos`, which is any nonnegative integer, `0, 1, 2, ...`.

To get its position on a line, do `linePos = pos % 16`. As such, `linePos` will assume values between `0` and `15`, inclusive.

To get the first position on the line, do `firstLinePos = (pos / 16) * 16`. Here, `/` is integer division, so you round any result down to the next lowest integer. `firstLinePos` will assume nonnegative integer values, same as `pos`.

Note that `pos - firstLinePos = linePos`; you can use this formula to calculate `linePos` or `firstLinePos`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this traversal:

```
for( uint idx = 0; idx < 1100; ++idx )
{
    if( 0 == ( 7 & ( idx >> 4 ) ) )
 // if( 0 == ( idx / 16 ) % ( 128 / 16 ) )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", idx );
    }
}
```